# zsh, zmv mass rename sub directories nothing happening on large volume of directories

Tags: rename, zsh

I've set

```
autoload -U zmv
alias mmv='noglob zmv -W'
```

When on sample data (~20 folders with subfolders) I run

```
mmv images/**/advert images/**/notice
```

it just works as expected. 
But if I run same command on real data (hundreds of thousands folders), nothing happends. I've run `mmv -n` to get some messages but no result. Even one directory name was changed so after I while I just ended the process.

Is `zmv` cache folder list as a first step and than it replace names? I expected that `zmv` will start changing names immediately dir by dir.

Should I run mvv and just wait for few hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zmv` computes all the renamings before it starts acting, so the behavior you observed is normal.

One of the reasons it does this is that it'll error out if two files are to be renamed to the same name. It also errors out if a file is to be renamed to a name that already exists, and it tries to find out about errors early on rather than aborting in the middle with a hard-to-determine set of files already renamed.